# React button not applying css until refresh Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have used the following syntax for adding the buttons in the side menu. All works well, but the button attribute does not show up until a refresh is done.

```
                <ListItem
                  button={true}
                  key="Home"
                  onClick={() => {
                    toggleSidebar();
                    navigate("/home", { replace: false });
                  }}
                >
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <HomeIcon />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary="Home" />
                </ListItem>
```

This is how it looks like on first load:-

[image: On first load]

After I refresh the page:-

[image: Upon refresh]

Comment: Are you using Nextjs ?

Comment: @prograk No ListItem from Material UI https://mui.com/components/lists/ directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<ListItem button={bool} is deprecated use ListItemButton instead.

[image]